# sql server compact deadlock caused by page-lock on index

Tags: .net, nhibernate, sql-server-ce, database-deadlocks, rowlocking

I am working on a c# desktop application using  **NHibernate** as data access layer and **SQL Server compact**. The application uses multiple threads to perform selects and updates of data.

In general it is working fine but sometimes **deadlock** situations arise.

> 15:28:16,750 55 WARN : System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeLockTimeoutException (0x80004005): Timeout ..... [ Session id = 28,Thread id = 14576,Process id = 12960,Table name = PatientOrder,Conflict type = x lock (x blocks),Resource = PAG (idx): 1035 ]

I can understand deadlock problems if two transactions try to update the same rows. However in this case both transactions are working on **different rows**. 
The deadlock seems to be caused by the **page lock** on an index (`Resource = PAG (idx): 1035`).

So my question is: ***What can be done to prevent these deadlocks?***

I already looked into the following options:

- Disable page locks for the index. This is possible for "full" SQL server but does not seem to be supported by the compact edition
- Configure hibernate to generate `with(rowlock)` for the sql statements that would (hopefully) prevent the problem
- Trying to use `session.lock(...)` to enforce resource access in the same order for all transactions. However this does not seem to help as the deadlocking transactions are working on different rows anyway
- Serialize all database transactions so that only one is active at a time. This does work but has a heavy performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

@Wolfgang How you are managing your ISession? ISession is not threadsafe, if you are using a single instance and sharing between threads this should be your problem. If you are using a IoC, verify the scope of ISession, change that for one per thread.